# Keyboard shortcut for highlighting text on webpages in IE 8?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I want to select text to copy on webpages using just the keyboard but all the shortcuts I found online are not working.  What's the real shortcut for this task?

Comment: Which ones did you find exactly?

Comment: What keys have you tried that didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use <kbd>F7</kbd> to get into caret browsing. Use <kbd>F6</kbd> to select between the address bar and the page display. Then you can use a combination of <kbd>PgUp</kbd>, <kbd>PgDn</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and the arrow keys <kbd><</kbd><kbd>^</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>></kbd> to move around. Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> while using the arrow keys to select a block of text and the standard <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> will select everything on the page including images, ads, flash, etc. so be careful with that.